# How to add some number to XML element's value (it's concatenating instead of adding)?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm stuck at adding 10(a number) to an element's value in XML linq...

So far I've come up with this code:

```
            XDocument XMLDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\...");

            var change = from block in XMLDoc.Descendants("Head")
                         where double.Parse(block.Element("Tenon").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < 13
                         select block.Element("Tenon");


            foreach (XElement x in change)
            {
                double number = 10;
                x.Value = (double.Parse(x.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + number).ToString();


                Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
             }

            XMLDoc.Save(@"C:\Users\...");

            Console.ReadLine();
```

aaaaaaaaaaaand I'm stuck.

It's concatenating instead of adding, I know x.Value is string, but I literally have no idea, cause I've tried pretty much everything... Can you help?

Comment: The problem is that you are changing the source while enumerating the source. Add a ToList() before your foreach, and you can change the source safely

Answer (score 0):

The provided code adds a number correctly. The only problem i see - you are only validating and selecting the first Tenon node from a Head.

Try the following linq expression instead:

```
var change = from block in XMLDoc.Descendants("Head")
                    from tenon in block.Elements("Tenon")
                    where double.Parse(tenon.Value) < 13
                    select tenon;
```